# Case status default to Closed on Close case layout

Tags: case

When clicking on the Close Case button the user is take to the Close Case layout.
Then they need to select 'Closed' from the status drop down, which is redundant because we have only one Close status.
How can I make 'Closed' the default so they won't need to select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed it by removing the button Close Case, and adding our own which passes a parameter. This is what the URL of your button must be to set the Closed status

`/{!Case.Id}/s?retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&cas7=Closed`

Replace `Closed` if you have another status.